# How to show webp image with falback url in image_tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, webp

I want to show webp image urls with their fallback urls in `image_tag` rails.

Now its `<%= image_tag "profile.webp",:class=>"profile" %>`

How can I add fallback url of `jpg` url for browsers on which webp not working

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this isn't possible using the rails helper (image_tag).

You can take a look at https://github.com/kavu/sprockets-webp as a possible solution, however, this adds a lot of complexity.

Your best bet is solving this using JS: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq

Answer (score 0):

well, you can achieve it not by rails way, but by basic HTML-5 WAY, using [picture tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="/img.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <source srcset="/img.jpg" type="image/jgpg" />
</picture>
```

Or in the below way too..

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="/images/cereal-box.webp" />
  <img src="/images/cereal-box.jpg" />
</picture>
```